# Hbase start error

Tags: hadoop, hbase

i start hbase.some region file is corrupt blocks

This error is :

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /master.jsp. Reason:

```
Trying to contact region server null for region , row '', but failed after 10 attempts.
```

Exceptions:
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}

Caused by:

org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Trying to contact region server null for region , row '', but failed after 10 attempts.
Exceptions:
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}
java.io.IOException: HRegionInfo was null or empty in -ROOT-, row=keyvalues={.META.,,1/info:server/1354594525394/Put/vlen=15, .META.,,1/info:serverstartcode/1354594525394/Put/vlen=8}

```
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getRegionServerWithRetries(HConnectionManager.java:1231)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.access$000(MetaScanner.java:45)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner$1.connect(MetaScanner.java:123)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner$1.connect(MetaScanner.java:120)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.execute(HConnectionManager.java:318)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:120)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:96)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:58)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.listTables(HConnectionManager.java:649)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTables(HBaseAdmin.java:217)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.generated.master.master_jsp._jspService(master_jsp.java:161)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer.java:835)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

How to fix it.Thank

Answer (score 0):

```
1)Verify your DNS settings or what you have given in the etc/hosts
  Hbase requires both forward and reverse resolving of hostname and IP. So add all the slave   
  and master ip in etc/hosts.

2) Check your regioserver file which is inside hbase/conf/regionserver
   remove localhost from every plcae, give somename  if so, because it will not be conflicted.
```